# Is Function(int) a Function(Object) in Dart?

Tags: dart

```
Function foo = (int x) => x;

if (foo is Function(Object)) { 
  print('Bar'); // Doesn't print
}
```

According to me, `Function(int)` is a subtype of `Function(Object)` since type `int` is subtype of type `Object` and hence the `if` condition should return `true` but it doesn't. Why is that so?

*I wasn't getting any good title for this question, feel free to change it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not.

The point of subtypes is that an instance of a subtype can be used everywhere an instance of the supertype is expected (also known as ["substitutability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

A `Function(Object)` can be called with *any* object as argument. It can be called with both `"foo"` and `42` as arguments.
A `Function(int)` *cannot* be called with a string as argument. That means that a `Function(int)` cannot be substituted where a `Function(Object)` is expected, and the type system does indeed not make `Function(int)` a subtype of `Function(Object)`.

It does make `Function(Object)` a subtype of `Function(int)` instead, because if a function which can be called with *any* argument, then it can be used anywhere a function accepting an `int` argument is needed - because it accepts an `int`.

In general, a `R1 Function(P1)` function type is a subtype of `R2 Function(P2)` if `R1` is a subtype of `R2` and `P2` is a subtype of `P1`. *Notice the reverse ordering of the parameter type.* Parameter types are [*covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Think of it as: A function can be used in a place where it's given an argument of type *P* and is expected to return a value of type *R* if (and only if) it accepts any *P* argument *and possibly more*, and the values it might return must all be *R* values *but not necessarily all *R* values*.

That is, a function type is a subtype of `R Function(P)` if it accepts *at least* `P` and returns *at most* `R`.

Comment: I am sure I won't find a better explanation than this anywhere on internet. Thanks a lot  Lasse sir.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not immediately intuitive, the subtyping is the opposite: `Function(Object)` is a subtype of `Function(int)`. Indeed, a type `A` can be a subtype of `B` only if anything that holds about `B`, also holds about `A`. `Function(Object)` can always be called with an `int` argument, but `Function(int)` cannot be called with an arbitrary `Object`, so:

```
Function foo = (Object x) => x;

if (foo is Function(int)) { 
   print('Bar'); // prints!
}
```

In other words, functions are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in the parameter type.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But`Function(int)` can also be called with an `Object`.

Comment: @iLoveFlutterDocs you cannot call `Function(int)` e.g. with a string, can you?

Comment: I think you got me wrong. If your `Object` is `int`, say `Object obj = 1`, then you can call a `Function(int)` with `obj`.

Comment: @iLoveFlutterDocs Ah I see what you mean. The Dart type system seems to be a bit more relaxed, so it omits some static checks for function calls. But it still applies to the `is` operator. Need to find if it's actually documented somewhere.